# where is std::cout windows in MacBook Pro?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am using MacBook Pro Mac OS 10.5 with related version of XCode. I am new to this development environment. I am developing C++ console/terminal applications (File->New project, then from the list on the left "Command line utility", and on the right "C++ tool".).

When statement like std::cout executes, I think the output should be on the console/terminal/command line, but I can not find such output from XCode IDE. Appreciate if anyone could tell me how to find output of std::cout from XCode IDE?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose **Run => Console** or press shift-command-R.

Comment: I think Run => Console just show the console window, and after the console window shows, I should use Build and Go to execute and debug, correct?

Comment: @George: Yep. Build and Run or Build and Debug. Mind the selection of Production or Debug build, though. You usually want Debug.